# mysql subquery only returning one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns many rows:

```
SELECT c.id AS courseID,
   c.fullname AS courseName,
   c.continuingeducationcredits AS cec,
   cc.name AS catName,
   IFNULL(ccp.name, '-No Parent Category-') AS catParent,
   ue.userid AS userID,
   CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS name,
   ud.data AS employeeid,
   date_format(date_add('1970-01-01',interval round(c.startdate/60/60/24) DAY), '%m/%d/%Y') AS startdate,
   u.id AS uid,
   c.startdate AS cstartdate
FROM user_enrolments AS ue
INNER
    JOIN USER AS u ON ue.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN user_info_data AS ud ON (ud.fieldid = 1
                                      AND ud.userid = u.id)
INNER JOIN enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
INNER JOIN course AS c ON c.id = e.courseid
INNER JOIN course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category
LEFT
    OUTER JOIN course_categories AS ccp ON ccp.id = cc.parent
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (cc.ID = 13
       OR ccp.ID = 13)
ORDER BY catParent,
         uid,
         cstartdate DESC
```

That works fine, and returns multiple rows. But if I try to use it as a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT c.id AS courseID,
          c.fullname AS courseName,
          c.continuingeducationcredits AS cec,
          cc.name AS catName,
          IFNULL(ccp.name, '-NO Parent Category-') AS catParent, ue.userid AS userID, CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS name,
          ud.data AS employeeid,
          date_format(date_add('1970-01-01',interval round(c.startdate/60/60/24) DAY), '%m/%d/%Y') AS startdate,
          u.id AS uid,
          c.startdate AS cstartdate
   FROM user_enrolments AS ue
   INNER JOIN USER AS u ON ue.userid = u.id
   INNER JOIN user_info_data AS ud ON (ud.fieldid = 1
                                       AND ud.userid = u.id)
   INNER JOIN enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
   INNER JOIN course AS c ON c.id = e.courseid
   INNER
    JOIN course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category
   LEFT OUTER JOIN course_categories AS ccp ON ccp.id = cc.parent
   WHERE 1 = 1
     AND (cc.ID = 13
          OR ccp.ID = 13)) AS Pseudotable
WHERE courseID = 8946
ORDER BY catParent,
         uid,
         cstartdate DESC
```

It will only ever return one row.

What am I doing wrong? :(

The first query is the inner query of the second query.

The first query gets all the users who attended a course within a category. The second is intended to filter that set, and get only the users who attended a single course.

Comment: Can you reduce the query to the core problem?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe **the specific problem** — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: It's because of this: `WHERE courseID = 8946`   remove that and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue ... the application is Moodle, and it loads queries into an array, using a function called get_records_sql.

It *requires* the first row of the results to be a unique key. It uses that row as the index of the array.

So ... to make that happen:

Begin the SELECT like this-

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 as serial_number, c.id as courseID,
```

And add this to the FROM clause-

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_course_categories AS ccp ON ccp.id = cc.parent, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a WHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

To be fair... my comment with this answer was first :)

```
WHERE courseID = 8946
```

Is in the second query. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: Next time post it as a answer directly. Because there is no need to post the same answer three time ;)

Comment: @TheEwook Yes, I should know better. Cheers.

Comment: I do need to filter by the course, but there should be multiple users in the results. The first query is the inner query of the second query. The first/inner query lists all the users who attended a course in the selected category. The second outer query is narrowing this down to a course. The problem is that there is only ever one user in the final, outer query result.

Comment: @GregHolmes When the inner/first query executes... are you sure that there actually ARE more than 1 where course is 8946? Because if there are then really this seems impossible.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  There are three.

Comment: @GregHolmes Ok, but if all the `join`s are the same... and the `where`s are the same AND there are 3 in the first (when run independently) that have that ID... then they _must_ show up in the larger query. May I ask how you are executing them - PHP/Workbench/etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have one row in your second query because of the `WHERE` condition which you haven't got in your first query.

```
WHERE courseID = 8946
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `WHERE courseID = 8946` which you are reducing your query down to one ID